# How to propagate HTTP responses cleanly to consumers of a typed HTTP client in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Is there a good way of propagating an object on a successful response or the status code and response body to consumers of a [typed HTTP client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#typed-clients) in ASP.NET Core?

Given the following API service:

```cs
public class TestApiService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public TestApiService(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5000");
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }

    public async Task<string> GetVersion()
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/api/v1/version");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

which is registered with the DI container via:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<TestApiService>();
```

I would like to return the `string` value from the `TestApiService.GetVersion()` method if the response was successful or if the response was not successful return the status code and the response body.

It doesn't appear to be possible to do something like:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetVersion()
{
    var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("/api/v1/version");

    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

and get the desired outcome because the [HttpRequestException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestexception) thrown from [HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.ensuresuccessstatuscode) does not include the status code or the response body.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/26477) about this on GitHub but I'm not sure if it will get implemented anytime soon or not.

While [ActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult-1) does exist it seems to really be for the controller layer so I'm not sure if using it here is an appropriate use of that class or not or if there is a better way of getting the desired outcome?

It should be possible to create my own exception class and throw that from the service but I would really like to avoid that if there is some built-in mechanism that is usable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() this is basically checking the status and if its not a 200 throwing the exception.  Consider using response.IsSuccessStatusCode or check the response status code manually.  Either way will prevent the raising of the exception which you don't want.

```
if (HttpStatusCode.Ok == response.StatusCode)
{
   // Read your result
}
else if ( // handle the specific failure case was it a 404 or a 401)
{
  string value = await response.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
  // Read your failed result
  return $"{response.StatusCode} {value}".Trim()";
}
```

The next question is how you handle and communicate failure to the callee's of your service? Do you want your service to be opaque to your client application?

Since your code is only returning a string, have you considered either returning something else such as an encompassing object { Success = true|false, Error = "", ErrorCode = 1234, Data = "value"} or simply throwing an appropriate exception to communicate the nature of the failure.  E.g. You might want to throw an appropriate exception, e.g. TestApiException where TestApiException might have the ErrorCode or whatever you need on it.

Comment: That was basically my thinking as well. Either throw my own custom exception or have a result-like object. Thanks!